# Asrock Motherboard Drivers

Tags: drivers, motherboard

Which motherboard driver/utilities are worth installing? The installation prompt seems to be listing a lot of adware/bloatware, but I imagine within these lists are useful utilities, like one that would tell me the internal temperature? Maybe a few designed to improve performance?

Model: ASRock 
H97M PRO4

Comment: Personally (I can't say for sure since I don't own that particular brand / model) just install the Drivers. Note: Not all of them are Drivers, some of them would be software made by them (or 3rd party) to "improve performance" or "do whatever they claim to do". The most standard things would be Chipset, Ethernet, Audio, and SATA/RAID/IDE/Storage related drivers. The rest are usually software that you may / may not care about. You can usually skip the CD installer as it will try to install all other stuff, by going to the Device Manager and update the devices needing drivers one by one.

Comment: Ya, they are listing google toolbar as a driver... That is why I decided install all was not going to work very well.